# How to execute sql script for PostgreSQL database hosted on AWS?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to run an sql file for a database hosted on AWS RDS. The command I am using is the following:

```
psql -v user=myusername -v dbname=postgres -v passwd=mypassword -f ./explorerpg.sql
```

After running it I get the following result:

```
sql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What am I missing? For those curious I am trying to get Hyperledger explorer to display the database contents of an AWS blockchain. The sql script is from Hyperledger explorer.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `-h` (or `--host`) option.  The command you're running is trying to connect to a PostgreSQL server on your localhost.  Additionally, you're trying too hard with the command line.  You want something more like:

```
psql -U myusername -d postgres -h dbhostname.randomcharacters.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -v passwd=mypassword -f ./explorerpg.sql
```

The password likely should not be done this way - a file containing the password is more common.  But the key is to find the hostname of your RDS server and specify it with the `-h` option.

Comment: Thank you for your response that answers my question. Unfortunately, by my own mistake I forgot to mention that user, dbname and passwd are in that format because inside sql file these variables are being used. To address that I appended the user, dbname and passwd variables as were declared in my original command to your command.